# Multiples Updates en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, plsql

Les comento,estoy desarrollando un validador de tablas. Primero creo la tabla con las columnas que necesito, después realizo algunos updates con informacion que se va a repetir en las columnas.

Sin embargo la ultima sección de updates que es donde actualizo la columna denominada `NUMERADOR`  para cada una de mis llaves primarias `ID_KQI`, tengo que validar si el campo de una de mis tablas tiene nulos y si los tiene que me lo ponga en ese registro. De momento eso lo hace de maravilla y tengo la salida que espero.

Sin embargo tengo la inquietud ¿hay forma de todos esos updates meterlos en un bucle dentro de SQL Server?

```
CREATE TABLE Parametria.dbo.TABLA_INPUT
    (ID_KQI varchar(100),  
    FECHA_PROCESO date,
    FECHA_CONTABLE date,
    NUMERADOR int,
    POBLACION_TOTAL int,
    ID_PRODUCTO varchar(10),
    ID_ENTIDAD varchar(4));



INSERT INTO Parametria.dbo.TABLA_INPUT (ID_KQI,POBLACION_TOTAL, NUMERADOR)
SELECT ID_KQI, (select COUNT(*) FROM FINREP.dbo.[CALIFICACION_IBM_TC.CALIFICACION]) AS POBLACION_TOTAL,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FINREP.dbo.[CALIFICACION_IBM_TC.CALIFICACION] WHERE CLIENTE IS NULL AND ID_KQI = '001-RCDAT_D001-1') AS NUMERADOR
FROM Parametria.dbo.FinRep A
WHERE NOMBRE_SISTEMA = 'CALIFICACION_IBM_TC' AND ID_TIPO_KQI = '001'
UPDATE Parametria.dbo.TABLA_INPUT SET ID_PRODUCTO = 'NA'
--UPDATE Parametria.dbo.TABLA_INPUT SET FECHA_CONTABLE = 'NA'
UPDATE Parametria.dbo.TABLA_INPUT SET FECHA_PROCESO = GETDATE()
UPDATE Parametria.dbo.TABLA_INPUT SET ID_ENTIDAD = 9157
--UPDATE Parametria.dbo.TABLA_INPUT SET NUMERADOR = count(*) FROM FINREP.dbo.['Cartera TC']
UPDATE Parametria.dbo.TABLA_INPUT SET NUMERADOR = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FINREP.dbo.[CALIFICACION_IBM_TC.CALIFICACION] WHERE [No# LINEA] IS NULL) WHERE ID_KQI = '001-RCDAT_D002-1';
UPDATE Parametria.dbo.TABLA_INPUT SET NUMERADOR = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FINREP.dbo.[CALIFICACION_IBM_TC.CALIFICACION] WHERE [No# CLIENTE] IS NULL) WHERE ID_KQI = '001-RCDAT_D003-1';
UPDATE Parametria.dbo.TABLA_INPUT SET NUMERADOR = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FINREP.dbo.[CALIFICACION_IBM_TC.CALIFICACION] WHERE [TIPO DE GARANTIA 1] IS NULL) WHERE ID_KQI = '001-SADAT_D004_1-1';
UPDATE Parametria.dbo.TABLA_INPUT SET NUMERADOR = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FINREP.dbo.[CALIFICACION_IBM_TC.CALIFICACION] WHERE [TIPO DE GARANTIA 2] IS NULL) WHERE ID_KQI = '001-SADAT_D004_2-1';
UPDATE Parametria.dbo.TABLA_INPUT SET NUMERADOR = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FINREP.dbo.[CALIFICACION_IBM_TC.CALIFICACION] WHERE [TIPO DE GARANTIA 3] IS NULL) WHERE ID_KQI = '001-SADAT_D004_3-1';
UPDATE Parametria.dbo.TABLA_INPUT SET NUMERADOR = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FINREP.dbo.[CALIFICACION_IBM_TC.CALIFICACION] WHERE [TIPO DE GARANTIA 4] IS NULL) WHERE ID_KQI = '001-SADAT_D004_4-1';
UPDATE Parametria.dbo.TABLA_INPUT SET NUMERADOR = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FINREP.dbo.[CALIFICACION_IBM_TC.CALIFICACION] WHERE [TIPO DE GARANTIA 5] IS NULL) WHERE ID_KQI = '001-SADAT_D004_5-1';
--UPDATE Parametria.dbo.TABLA_INPUT SET NUMERADOR = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FINREP.dbo.[CALIFICACION_IBM_TC.CALIFICACION] WHERE [PARI PASSU NOMBRE GARANTE] IS NULL) WHERE ID_KQI = '001-SADAT_D009-1';
UPDATE Parametria.dbo.TABLA_INPUT SET NUMERADOR = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FINREP.dbo.[CALIFICACION_IBM_TC.CALIFICACION] WHERE [(B)+(C)+(D)+(E)+(F)=                      RESERVAS TOTALES] IS NULL) WHERE ID_KQI = '001-RCDAT_M002-1';
UPDATE Parametria.dbo.TABLA_INPUT SET NUMERADOR = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FINREP.dbo.[CALIFICACION_IBM_TC.CALIFICACION] WHERE [$ GARANTIA 1] IS NULL) WHERE ID_KQI = '001-SADAT_M003_1-1';
UPDATE Parametria.dbo.TABLA_INPUT SET NUMERADOR = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FINREP.dbo.[CALIFICACION_IBM_TC.CALIFICACION] WHERE [$ GARANTIA 2] IS NULL) WHERE ID_KQI = '001-SADAT_M003_2-1';
UPDATE Parametria.dbo.TABLA_INPUT SET NUMERADOR = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FINREP.dbo.[CALIFICACION_IBM_TC.CALIFICACION] WHERE [$ GARANTIA 3] IS NULL) WHERE ID_KQI = '001-SADAT_M003_3-1';
UPDATE Parametria.dbo.TABLA_INPUT SET NUMERADOR = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FINREP.dbo.[CALIFICACION_IBM_TC.CALIFICACION] WHERE [$ GARANTIA 4] IS NULL) WHERE ID_KQI = '001-SADAT_M003_4-1';
UPDATE Parametria.dbo.TABLA_INPUT SET NUMERADOR = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FINREP.dbo.[CALIFICACION_IBM_TC.CALIFICACION] WHERE [$ GARANTIA 5] IS NULL) WHERE ID_KQI = '001-SADAT_M003_5-1';
--UPDATE Parametria.dbo.TABLA_INPUT SET NUMERADOR = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FINREP.dbo.[CALIFICACION_IBM_TC.CALIFICACION] WHERE [PARI PASSU $ GARANTIA] IS NULL) WHERE ID_KQI = '001-SADAT_M010-1';
SELECT * FROM Parametria.dbo.TABLA_INPUT
```

Comment: ¿Cómo obtendrías el ID_KQI y su relación con las columnas con un bucle? No haría un bucle, pero se puede hacer en una sola instrucción.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres de en una sola instrucción Luis? ¿Cómo podría lograr eso?

Comment: Si existe una forma de vincular el código de KQI con la columna que corresponde, se podría generar una instrucción dinámica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta es una forma de hacer todo en una sola instrucción. No requiere que se hagan UPDATEs posteriores porque todos los datos se insertan desde el inicio. Para eso,

- realizamos un agregado condicional.
- Luego convertimos las columnas en filas y para eso me apoyo de las capacidades de la instrucción VALUES para generar tablas de valores y la expresión APPLY para llamar a
  columnas de otras tablas.
- Finalmente, hago el JOIN con la tabla de
  origen.

```
    WITH ConteoNulos AS(
        --Primero obtenemos todos los conteos en una sola lectura de la tabla
        SELECT  COUNT( CASE WHEN [CLIENTE]            IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS '001-RCDAT_D001-1',
                COUNT( CASE WHEN [No# LINEA]          IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS '001-RCDAT_D002-1',
                COUNT( CASE WHEN [No# CLIENTE]        IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS '001-RCDAT_D003-1',
                COUNT( CASE WHEN [TIPO DE GARANTIA 1] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS '001-SADAT_D004_1-1',
                COUNT( CASE WHEN [TIPO DE GARANTIA 2] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS '001-SADAT_D004_2-1',
                COUNT( CASE WHEN [TIPO DE GARANTIA 3] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS '001-SADAT_D004_3-1',
                COUNT( CASE WHEN [TIPO DE GARANTIA 4] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS '001-SADAT_D004_4-1',
                COUNT( CASE WHEN [TIPO DE GARANTIA 5] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS '001-SADAT_D004_5-1',
                COUNT( CASE WHEN [(B)+(C)+(D)+(E)+(F)=                      RESERVAS TOTALES] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS '001-RCDAT_M002-1',
                COUNT( CASE WHEN [$ GARANTIA 1]       IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS '001-SADAT_M003_1-1',
                COUNT( CASE WHEN [$ GARANTIA 2]       IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS '001-SADAT_M003_2-1',
                COUNT( CASE WHEN [$ GARANTIA 3]       IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS '001-SADAT_M003_3-1',
                COUNT( CASE WHEN [$ GARANTIA 4]       IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS '001-SADAT_M003_4-1',
                COUNT( CASE WHEN [$ GARANTIA 5]       IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS '001-SADAT_M003_5-1',
                COUNT(*) AS Poblacion_Total
        FROM FINREP.dbo.[CALIFICACION_IBM_TC.CALIFICACION] 
    ),
    ConteoNulosUnpivot AS(
        --Luego convertimos las columnas en filas, pero mantenemos la columna de población total.
        SELECT KQI, Conteo, Poblacion_Total
        FROM ConteoNulos
        CROSS APPLY (VALUES( '001-RCDAT_D002-1',   [001-RCDAT_D002-1]),
                           ( '001-RCDAT_D003-1',   [001-RCDAT_D003-1]),
                           ( '001-SADAT_D004_1-1', [001-SADAT_D004_1-1]),
                           ( '001-SADAT_D004_2-1', [001-SADAT_D004_2-1]),
                           ( '001-SADAT_D004_3-1', [001-SADAT_D004_3-1]),
                           ( '001-SADAT_D004_4-1', [001-SADAT_D004_4-1]),
                           ( '001-SADAT_D004_5-1', [001-SADAT_D004_5-1]),
                           ( '001-RCDAT_M002-1',   [001-RCDAT_M002-1]),
                           ( '001-SADAT_M003_1-1', [001-SADAT_M003_1-1]),
                           ( '001-SADAT_M003_2-1', [001-SADAT_M003_2-1]),
                           ( '001-SADAT_M003_3-1', [001-SADAT_M003_3-1]),
                           ( '001-SADAT_M003_4-1', [001-SADAT_M003_4-1]),
                           ( '001-SADAT_M003_5-1', [001-SADAT_M003_5-1]))u(KQI,Conteo)
    )--Insertamos los valores sin necesidad de actualizar posteriormente
    INSERT INTO Parametria.dbo.TABLA_INPUT (
        ID_KQI,
        FECHA_PROCESO, 
        NUMERADOR,
        POBLACION_TOTAL,
        ID_PRODUCTO,
        ID_ENTIDAD)
    SELECT fr.ID_KQI, 
        GETDATE(),
        u.Conteo,
        Poblacion_Total,
        'NA',
        9157
    FROM Parametria.dbo.FinRep fr
    JOIN ConteoNulosUnpivot u ON fr.KQI = u.KQI
    WHERE fr.NOMBRE_SISTEMA = 'CALIFICACION_IBM_TC' 
    AND   fr.ID_TIPO_KQI = '001';
```